# Freeze and "break apart" an object. How?

Tags: temperature, freezing

Is it possible to freeze an object, say an apple, and then drop it so that is will break apart into pieces? And if so, how can it be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is possible. The usual way to cool down object to this temperature, is by putting it in liquid nitrogen. For an example, consider [this movie](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ihhPjjN5rQ), where it is done with a tulip. The water inside the object is freezing, which makes it breakable (as you can break ice, but not water).

Comment: thank you! is there any alternative for nitrogen? something for DIY?

Comment: I think it is sufficient to bring the temperature well below zero, but with nitrogren you can do this by far the fastest. What is DIY?

Comment: @Bernhard Do It Yourself

Comment: As you say, I think it needs to be significantly below zero to get the shattering effect which makes me wonder if there's something required *additional* to just the freezing of the water content?

Comment: how much is "significantly" enough? will -5°C do? or, as in case with nitrogen more than -40°C and so? Is there any relation between the mass (water content) and the temperature in this case?

Comment: @twistor59 sugar/water mixtures stay plastic quite a long way below zero. You need pretty aggressive cooling to get wholly brittle fracture. Dry ice would probably do it.

Comment: @OlehSky Alternatives? Sure, you could use liquid argon...but you don't gain anything as it is more expensive. Or liquid hydrogen or oxygen, but those present more hazards. Something *DIY?* Doubt it. For something with substantial water content (like an apple) you could try dry ice. I don't know if that will be cold enough. LN2 is inexpensice as cryomaterials go and relatively safe to handle (which is not to say that you can't get hurt if you do something stupid: best to learn from someone with experience).

Comment: @OlehSky The temperature of the coolant determines that by which the object decreases in temperature. Therefor, the tulip in liquid nitrogen cools 'instantly'.

Comment: @dmckee I've asked about alternatives, as heard of "dry ice + alcohol", which cools close to LN2. Thought to hear more "alternatives". Thanks for your answer, doubt I will mess with argon :)

Comment: @OlehSky: dry ice and alcohol is nowhere near as cold as liquid nitrogen, but apparently it can cause similar effects - http://amasci.com/amateur/liquid_n2.html